# Why is the Orders tab empty in the Experience Profile?

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am trying to figure out how the data which is shown in the Orders tab in the Experience Profile is populated.

Currently this is empty (No orders found) but in the Overview tab I can see value for the placed orders. In the Products tab there is also data for the "Products purchased" table.

Any advise where to look at to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Is xconnect working together with sitecore commerce ? Check the certificate thumbprint in showconfig.aspx which should originate from the sitecore commerce configs from sitecore side.

Comment: The certificate thumbprints should match as I had issues before and looked into it.

Comment: The only other suggestion I can think of is try to put an order through properly, and look at the error logs. Completed orders are stored as an Outcome, so ensure the outcome is definitely run. You can look at the order submission pipeline from sitecore end and try your best to follow it. Any tracker error will also indicate that the analytics events may not fired properly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It indeed has to do with the order submission pipeline. See my posted answer which I got from Sitecore support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer from Sitecore support (see below). It indeed has todo with the order submission pipeline and that an outcome hasn't been registrered. After enabling the TriggerOrderOutcome processor the Orders tab in the Experience Profile shows orders as result.

> As for the reported issue, I am able to reproduce it on my side. The
>   issue is related to the fact that the mentioned tabs get the data from
>   different places:
>
> Commerce->Overview tab reports all the orders which were registered as
>   a Sitecore.Commerce.CustomModels.Goals.VisitorOrderCreatedGoal
>   interaction. whereas Commerce->Orders tab reports all the order which
>   were registered as a
>   Sitecore.Commerce.CustomModels.Outcomes.SubmittedOrderOutcome
>   interaction.
>
> The Sitecore.Commerce.CustomModels.Outcomes.SubmittedOrderOutcome is
>   registered on a submitVisitorOrder pipeline.
>
> But as far as I can see the processor is disabled by default.
>
> In order to make it register such a type of data, please open the
>   "App_Config\Include\Sitecore.Commerce.Orders.config" file and
>   uncomment the "Sitecore.Commerce.Pipelines.Orders.TriggerOrderOutcome"
>   processor.
>
> The behavior you reported was registered as a bug in our bug tracking
>   system. Thank you for reporting the problem.
>
> To track the future status of this bug report, please use the
>   reference number 329511. More information about public reference
>   numbers can be found here: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/853187

Comment: Just wondering, what version of sitecore and sitecore commerce is this ?

Comment: This is on Sitecore XC 9.2